# Running remote scripts on Linux Servers from Windows

Tags: linux, windows, script, remote, remote-access

I'm on a Windows server, I'm looking for a way to run some scripts (through RSH?) remotely on Linux servers.

Thing is, I have to do a lot of stuff manually on different servers whenever I want to test something and I'd like to automate it, also to make it less error-prone.

Is there any way to do this?

Currently I'm just logged in to SSH terminals with Putty and run the scripts locally on the Linux servers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are already using great protocol for remote access (SSH). I would recommend you to use it for running commands remotely too. PuTTY you mentioned contains also a text console SSH client [`plink`](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink). If the remote scripts are not very interactive the best option would be to use `plink`:

```
plink [options] [user@]host [command]
```

If the script is highly interactive it could be better to use the classical GUI PuTTY.

```
putty -ssh -l user -pw password -m command.txt host
```

In this case you have to create a file (`command.txt`) and store the command to execute there. Here is more information about [PuTTY command line](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline).

For this use of SSH it could be very helpful to use a public key authentication instead of passwords. Then it is possible to run the commands without entering a password. See for example: [Public Key Authentication With PuTTY](http://www.ualberta.ca/CNS/RESEARCH/LinuxClusters/pka-putty.html) or [Key-Based SSH Logins With PuTTY](http://www.howtoforge.com/ssh_key_based_logins_putty).

Comment: Apparently, you can also set the command in the ssh panel of your configuration - http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-command